# Ad hoc iOS app - distribute it without itunes

Tags: ios, itunes, ad-hoc-distribution

I have created an app (I have the .ipa file) with ad hoc provisioning profile. I have included 5 devices in the provisioning file (one is mine and the others belong to other people in my team). Now I don't know how to install it on their devices. If I try it with iTunes, by double-clicking on the .ipa file I have to authorize their devices on my mac, I don't think this is the right way to go... Of course I don't want to do App Review submission. I'll do it when the passes first tests.

Comment: r u want to check the ipa in your device na, then wat the purpose of Appsubmission , this is not the necessary one. you can directly check this in your device

Comment: use diawi link for without iTunes for install the app directly in your device

Comment: http://www.diawi.com/ this is the simplest, no limitations for testers, no pricing, no need to create account, just upload app and share URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make tests between teammates, I would recommend to use [testfairy](http://testfairy.com/).

TestFlight is other option, but it has some drawbacks:

1. iOS 8 only
2. Build is not always available instantly for testing (Apple build processing time varies much)

Comment: you can. testfairy is just webpage, where you can upload .ipa to share it with your teammates. implementing their SDK is optional

Answer (score 7):

You can create a simple webpage your teammates to be able to download it using their device. It is a [description](http://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/) about it.

Or - I recommend you this way - you can use the Apple TestFlight services, a great tutorial [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224).

Comment: as @f3n1kc says, testflight works only for ios8, while I have an ios7 device. The link you posted is for pre-xcode 6, when you could create an archive with enterprise AND ad-hoc profile.